# How to fix Linux paths created by CMake Tools in ".vscode\c_cpp_properties.json" in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I am preparing to develop a cross-platform project with CMake and so I used Cmake Tools and it created following `compilerPath`s:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "cStandard": "c18",
        "cppStandard": "c++20",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
        "compilerArgs": [],
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
        "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
        "cStandard": "c18",
        "cppStandard": "c++20",
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
        "compilerArgs": [],
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
        }
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

In `PROBLEMS` tab I see `Cannot find "\usr\bin\gcc".` and that's obvious, because I am on Windows, but

1. the `name` values `Linux` and `Win32` have some special meanings and
2. the paths have not been generated by me, but automatically so

I would expect the "`PROBLEM`" should not be there.

So how to correctly fix the "`PROBLEM`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to switch the config.

On the bottom right it should say Linux (the name of the config).

Click on Linux and switch to Win32.

I got the same error on Windows when my config was set to Linux. When switching to the Win32 config I get no error.